# The “backspace” character '\b' in the Android Edittext does not work?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to look at someone else's code on developing android virtual keyboards.

I have a gesture[swipeLeft] hooked to one of the backspace gesture and I use the following to implement that:

```
playSound(backspacePlayer); // background sound
InputConnection connection = getCurrentInputConnection();
connection.commitText("\b", 1);
```

**My main problem is that I can hear the sound of the backspace but it is not executed in the EditText.  I mean that the characters do NOT get erased in the EditText.**

Is the code I'm using okay? or is there a problem with commiting "\b" to text.
Also this code works for all other characters except backspace!

Any help would be awesome !
Adit

Comment: Have you tried tying in edittext's OnEditorAction? Or are you really just making a virtual keyboard and have to use InputConnections and all that jazz?

Comment: Yes shark, I have to use the InputConnections etc. coz I'm making a completely different virtual keyboard! This "\b" thing is eating my brains since a few days!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found my answer without getting into the hassel of "Inputconnections"

```
 keyDownUp(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)
```

This simulates the pressing of the delete key!

Gave me the required backspace I needed for my EditText!
Yay!